# qemu-system-armel.exe has stopped working in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I am learning Android. I am trying to print "Hello World". But whenever I start my AVD I get

> qemu-system-armel.exe has stopped.

I changed RAM size from 1536MB to 1024MB but no use. Then I reduced it to 512MB but found the same problem. I changed the resolution also but no use.

I am using Nexus S API 25 with resolution 480X800 hdpi and armeabi-v7a system image.

I am getting this on starting AVD:

> Problem signature
>
> Problem event name:APPCRASH
>
> Application name:qemu-system-armel.exe
>
> Application version:0.0.0.0
>
> etc....

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: improved formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android Studio emulator needs atleast 4GB of RAM for it's operation. I had only 2GB RAM which was the root of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered this problem.You can try myways:

1.Edit your avd and change the default option which is named as 'Graphics' to 'Software' or 'Hardware'.
2.Choose the low level Android API,I choose the Android 5.1(api 22) and it did work.The high level `APIS(>22)` always failed, I don't know why.
3.This way maybe sophisticated. Build your app in Android Studio, and find your wrapped app in `/Project/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk` and then send this apk to your Android phone, install it. (Besides make sure your phone has been in 'developer model')